# On hover add / remove class - not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm implementing some animation by adding and removing classes to an element on mouseover and mouseout. I'm using this method as I found using CSS alone was not reliable; the animation would not complete if the mouse exited the element before the animation finished.

So I have the following code:

```
<div class="one flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(".flip-container").hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass("hover");
    },function () {
        jQuery(this).delay(2000).queue(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .flipper {
        transition: 0.6s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

This works but sometimes the class 'hover' is not removed, it stays, leaving the element in its animated state. Any idea how to make this more reliable?

Comment: put HTML code as example

Comment: What's the CSS for `.hover`? Seeing a working example in a snippet or a http://jsfiddle.net would really help you get some answers

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mouseenter and then set a timeout function to remove the class that way you wont be adding and removing classes except once each time the mouse enters the area.  Also you may want to check to see if the area already has the class to avoid the function from being executed too many times like so:

```
jQuery(".flip-container").mouseenter(function () {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    if(!el.hasClass("hover")){
        el.addClass("hover");
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            el.removeClass("hover");
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/fts5pmjf/)